# Cannot instantiate the type in java

Tags: java

I was trying to run this code:

```
public class inventory {
    private static item[] inventory;
    static java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);          
    private static int noOfItems;       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        noOfItems=0;        

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        inventory=new item[10];
        run();      
    }

    public static int displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("1.Add Item");
        System.out.println("2.Find Item");
        System.out.println("3.Delete Item");
        System.out.println("4.Count Item");
        System.out.println("5.Exit");
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice:");
        int i=scanner.nextInt();
        return i;   
    }

    public static void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            int i=displayMenu();
            switch(i)
            {
            case 1:addItem();
                    break;
            case 2:findItem();
                    break;
            case 4:countItem();
                    break;
            case 5:return;
            default:System.out.println("Invalid choice");
            }
        }
    }

    public static <Item> void addItem()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Item namme:");
        String item_name=scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Enter barcode:");
        String barcode=scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Enter price:");
        double price=scanner.nextDouble();
        Item b=new Item(item_name,barcode,price);
        if(noOfItems==inventory.length)
            System.out.println("Array is full");
        else
        {
            inventory[noOfItems++]=b;
            System.out.println("Item added successfully");
        }
    }   

    public static void findItem()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter item name:");
        String item_name=scanner.next();
        for(int i=0; i<noOfItems; i++)
        {
            if(item_name.equalsIgnoreCase(inventory[i].getItem_name()))
            {
                System.out.println("Item found:");
                System.out.print(inventory[i]);
                return;
            }                           
        }       

    }

    public static void countItems()
    {
        System.out.println("Num of items:"+noOfItems);
        for(int i=0; i< noOfItems; i++)
            System.out.println(inventory[i]);
    }
}
```

Then, I got the error in "Item b=new Item(item_name,barcode,price);" about `"Cannot instantiate the type in java"`

```
public class item {
    private String item_name;
    private String barcode;
    private double price;

    //To initialise the state of the object
    public void Item(String item_name,String barcode,double price)
    {
        this.item_name=item_name;
        this.barcode=barcode;
        this.price=price;
    }

    //Reader methods i.e behavior methods
    public String getItem_name()
    {
        return item_name;
    }

    public String getBarcode()
    {
        return barcode;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    //Writer methods or setter methods
    public void setTitle(String item_name)
    {
        this.item_name=item_name;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        if(price < 0)
                    System.out.println("Price cannot be negative");
        else
            this.price=price;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode)
    {
        this.barcode=barcode;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Item name:"+item_name+",Barcode:"+barcode+",Price:"+price;
    }
}
```

And this is another code that I refer to the first one, actually the program didn't run properly too. Are there anyone can help me and fix the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

#### 1. The Constructor return type

A constructor **has no return type** so simply remove `void` in `public void Item(String item_name,String barcode,double price)` otherwise it won't be seen as constructor but as a normal method.

```
public Item(String item_name,String barcode,double price)
{
    this.item_name=item_name;
    this.barcode=barcode;
    this.price=price;
}
```

#### 2. The Class name

Java is a **case sensitive language** such that you need to use the exact same name (case included) between your constructor and your class name so here if your constructor is `public Item(String item_name,String barcode,double price)` your class name should be `Item` not `item`. You will need to fix the class name everywhere in your code otherwise it won't work.

#### 3. The bounded type of `addItem`

You need to remove `<Item>` from the method declaration of `addItem()` otherwise the compiler will be confused about the bounded type `Item` such that it won't compile.

So it should be:

```
public static void addItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified return type for your Constructor.
Remove that.

Change

```
public void Item(String item_name,String barcode,double price)
{
    this.item_name=item_name;
    this.barcode=barcode;
    this.price=price;
}
```

to

```
public Item(String item_name,String barcode,double price)
{
    this.item_name=item_name;
    this.barcode=barcode;
    this.price=price;
}
```

Constructors shouldn't have return type.

Comment: This fixes one of the three problems, but not the one OP has mentioned in his posted error message (well and another issue which you've also missed).